# google oauth scope issue

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I am working on developing Google OAuth within a NestJS server and have encountered an issue related to scopes.

First, when trying to obtain an authorization code by navigating to the following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=false&response_type=code&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=${process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI}&client_id=${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
```

I immediately get redirected to the following page:

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /auth/google?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&code=4%2F0Adeu5BWtQyrHhMJngRHJz13QrIgmy2ZQhzYnBPzvg3vkD0PKuHqEZ2fNLpV0e_ab3fn_PA&scope=profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile","error":"Not Found"}
```

And when I use the obtained authorization code to make a request to:

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

I encounter the following error:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

The most puzzling aspect of the issue is related to the scope within the URI for obtaining the authorization code under the same conditions as mentioned above. Initially, in the Google Developer Console, I allowed only the 'email' and 'profile' scopes. However, when I included these two scopes in the 'scope' parameter, I encountered the aforementioned error. Strangely, if I included a scope that I did not personally permit, such as 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar', I could successfully obtain the token.

To summarize, when I include the scopes that I have allowed, I receive the mentioned error, but when I include scopes that I have not allowed in the console, I can successfully obtain the token. I'm curious about how I can ensure that I receive the 'email' and 'profile' scopes as configured.

Could you please provide insights on how I can achieve receiving the 'email' and 'profile' scopes as intended?